# Xcode 6 and EZAudio: 'AudioUnitSampleType' is deprecated and no AudioPlotGL graph

Tags: ios, swift, deprecated

I'm using EZAudio for a sound recording and playing app in iPhone, with Xcode 6 Beta 3 and Swift.

At this time I've successfully compiled and deployed the app for testing both in the simulator and my device (until I installed Xcode 6 Beta 3. Now It only runs in simulator).

Xcode 6 identifies 20 warning issues for EZAudio, in the classes: EZOutput, EZAudioFile and EZAudio with the following messages:

```
"'AudioUnitSampleType' is deprecated: The concept of canonical formats is deprecated"
"'kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical' is deprecated: The concept of canonical formats is deprecated"
"'AudioSessionGetProperty' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0"
"Apple Mach-O Linker warning: relocatable dylibs (e.g. embedded frameworks) are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib)"
```

When compiled, the app can record a sound and play it. The problem is in the live recording sound graph. I added an EZAudioPilotGL var to the ViewController class:

@IBOutlet var audioPlot: EZAudioPlotGL

Its dimensions: w: 320, h: 62. View Mode: Scale to Fill.

I also included the following lines in the viewDidLoad method.

```
self.microphone = EZMicrophone(delegate: self) 
self.audioPlot.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
self.audioPlot.color = UIColor.orangeColor()
self.audioPlot.plotType = EZPlotType.Rolling
self.audioPlot.opaque = false
self.view.opaque = false
self.audioPlot.shouldFill = true
self.audioPlot.shouldMirror = true
```

I have ported to Swift all the methods implemented in the example project EZAudioRecordExample, including the microphone methods and the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method:

```
  func microphone(microphone: EZMicrophone, hasAudioReceived buffer: CMutablePointer<Float>, withBufferSize bufferSize: UInt32, withNumberOfChannels numberOfChannels: UInt32) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
      println("Updating AudioPlot Buffer")
      self.audioPlot.updateBuffer(buffer, withBufferSize: bufferSize)
      println("bufferSize \(bufferSize)")
    })
  }

  func microphone(microphone: EZMicrophone, hasBufferList bufferList:CMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>, withBufferSize bufferSize:UInt32, withNumberOfChannels numberOfChannels:UInt32){
    println(microphone)
    println(bufferList)
    if (self.isRecording) {
          self.recorder!.appendDataFromBufferList(bufferList, withBufferSize:bufferSize)
        }
  }

  func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    self.isPlaying = false
    togglePlaying()
  }
```

During the recording session, the AudioPilot remains just black, with no graph appearing.

I Also verified the ported methods are being called.

Any help for a solution would be very appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same warnings, but my app uses Core Audio directly.